# Kafka Consumer Java Maven Template

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I want to write a kafka consumer on top of confluent kafka.

What is the current best java maven template for kafka consumer ?

Answer (score 0):

A few good examples of Java repos that are build with maven and import Apache Kafka dependencies are presented by several Connectors, such as:

- the [kafka-connect-elasticsearch](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch) connector (single-module), or
- the [kafka-connect-storage-cloud](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud) connector (multi-module)

You might find the `pom.xml` files in these repos to be a good starting point for your code structuring.

They've been recently updated to import their common dependencies and other related build information from a common repo, here:
  https://github.com/confluentinc/common